How to calculate correlation from a table of data
This is not for the real statistic work...
But I need this for simple statistics for students of 15 year of age. To interpretate simple correlation in combination of a scatterplot. (Exam questions). Once I have a basic working example, I can make tons of questions. –
I can draw a scatterplot out of table of data, I can (with the help of others) draw the regression line.
But now I want to calculate the correlation with the data of the table.
I already looked at
How to display R^2 value using pgfplots?
But I was not able to adapt it to the solution I want.
So in this example, where XXXXX is printed, I want the correlation (Pearson)
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstableread{
    x   y   
    70.6    68
    66.2    66.3
    73.9    74.1
    68.2    71.3
    64.2    56.7
    69.8    69.6
    60.3    62.4
    56.8    57.6
    55  55.1
    67  65.2
    57.9    55.7
    57.9    59.6
    53.1    55.3
    61.2    59
    66.2    66.6
    56.9    52.3
    58  57.3
    78.5    79.9
    63.5    62.5
    51  54.1
    62.4    67.5
    50.5    50.2
    61.7    62.4
    70.5    73.5
}\tableWisFysTrendlijn
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=title,
    axis lines=center,
    axis x discontinuity=crunch,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    ymin=30, ymax=100,
    xmin=30, xmax=100,
    height=10cm,
    width=\linewidth,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={A},
ylabel={B},
    scatter/classes={a={mark=*,draw=black}}]
\addplot[only marks,  mark size = 1pt] table{\tableWisFysTrendlijn};
\addplot[no marks,red, thick] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}] {\tableWisFysTrendlijn};
\legend{leerling, $y= \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
    \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

The equation is $y= \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x  \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$\\
The correlation is: XXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{document}


See \pgfplotstablegetelim.

The linked example works with a few modifications.
First, the use of the default variable \tableLabel in the original code is a bit confusing, I have removed that. This means that you need to provide the macro that stores the table (in your case \tableWisFysTrendlijn) as the first of seven arguments.
Second, you read the table inside of \begin{center}, which means that the variable \tableWisFysTrendlijn was defined only in that scope. Therefore it could not be used outside of the center environment for calculation or printing of the correlation value. Moving \pgfplotstableread outside of the environment fixes that.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcommand\MakeRegression[7]{%
    % #1: original datatable
    % #2: x-column
    % #3: y-column
    % #4: name of new regression column
    % #5: macro to store slope in
    % #6: macro to store intercept in
    % #7: macro to store R squared
    % create the regression column:
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={x=#2,y=#3}]{#4}{#1}
    % store slope and intercept
    \edef#5{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
    \edef#6{\pgfplotstableregressionb}

    % calculate sum of y
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma+\thisrow{#3}}]{tmp}{#1}

    % find number of rows in table
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastrow}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

    % get total sum of y
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\lastrow}{tmp}\of#1

    % calculate mean
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yMean}{\pgfplotsretval/(\lastrow+1)}

    % calculate residuals and diff from mean
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
      create col/assign/.code={
           \pgfmathparse{(\thisrow{#3}-\thisrow{#4})^2}
           \edef\entry{\pgfmathresult}
           \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
        }
    ]{residuals}{#1}
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
      create col/assign/.code={
           \pgfmathparse{(\thisrow{#3}-\yMean)^2}
           \edef\entry{\pgfmathresult}
           \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
        }
    ]{diffmean}{#1}

    % calculate sum of residuals and diff from mean
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma+\thisrow{residuals}}]{sumres}{#1}
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma+\thisrow{diffmean}}]{sumdiff}{#1}

    % extract SS_res and SS_tot
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\lastrow}{sumres}\of#1
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\SSres}{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\lastrow}{sumdiff}\of#1
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\SStot}{\pgfplotsretval}

    % calculate r
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#7}{sqrt(1-\SSres/\SStot)}
}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
    x   y   
    70.6    68
    66.2    66.3
    73.9    74.1
    68.2    71.3
    64.2    56.7
    69.8    69.6
    60.3    62.4
    56.8    57.6
    55  55.1
    67  65.2
    57.9    55.7
    57.9    59.6
    53.1    55.3
    61.2    59
    66.2    66.6
    56.9    52.3
    58  57.3
    78.5    79.9
    63.5    62.5
    51  54.1
    62.4    67.5
    50.5    50.2
    61.7    62.4
    70.5    73.5
}\tableWisFysTrendlijn

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=title,
    axis lines=center,
    axis x discontinuity=crunch,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    ymin=30, ymax=100,
    xmin=30, xmax=100,
    height=10cm,
    width=\linewidth,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={A},
ylabel={B},
    scatter/classes={a={mark=*,draw=black}}]
\addplot[only marks,  mark size = 1pt] table{\tableWisFysTrendlijn};
\addplot[no marks,red, thick] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}] {\tableWisFysTrendlijn};
\legend{leerling, $y= \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
    \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

The equation is $y= \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x  \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$

\MakeRegression{\tableWisFysTrendlijn}{x}{y}{reg1}{\SlA}{\IntA}{\RsqA}
The correlation is: \RsqA

\end{document}



thanks, changed r^2 to r :-)

My suggestion is real statistics with R integrated with knitr, nor only because is easier make any calculus and will be more exact, including make the plots, but mainly because can extract easily data or results of the R side  and insert automatically in the LaTeX text in each compilation.
Therefore, if you make a problem with data generated randomly, you can obtain not only a different plot in  each compilation, but also a complete rewrite of your text. If you have 100 students, you need a single document compiled 100 times to obtain 100 different problems and solutions.  Except if you  use set.seed() the document will completely different in each compilation, but always correct (or always wrong in the same sense, by your fault).
An example:

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{parskip,booktabs}
\usepackage[columnsep=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

<<data, echo=F, results="asis">>=

# set.seed(34) # add this to NOT change the problem

subject <-  "weight in versus height ($y$)"
vars <- list("kg","cm")


d <- data.frame(
  x = sort(round(runif(20, min = 45 , max = 99),1)),
  y = sort(round(jitter(runif(20, min = 155, max = 195),amount=10),1)))   

@

\section*{The problem:} We have a set of fake data of   \Sexpr{subject} with $x$ values between \Sexpr{combine_words(range(d$x))} \Sexpr{vars[1]} and $y$ values in the range of \Sexpr{combine_words(range(d$y))}  \Sexpr{vars[2]}, paired as showed in the table.  

Questions: 

\begin{enumerate}
\item What is the Pearson $r$ coefficient?  
\item  There is a significant correlation between $x$ an $y$? 
\item What is the intercept and the slope of the regression line?
\end{enumerate}

<<kable, echo=F, results="asis">>=
TheTable <- kable(d, caption="The table.", booktabs = T)
kableExtra::kable_styling(TheTable, latex_options = "hold_position")
@


\newpage

\section*{The solution:} 

<<model,echo=F>>=
model <- lm(y ~ x, data = d)
cortest <- cor.test(d$x,d$y)
@


\begin{enumerate}

\item The \Sexpr{cortest$method} test show a coefficient of \mbox{$r = \Sexpr{round(cortest$estimate,2)}$}. 

\item This coefficient have a signification of  \mbox{$p =\Sexpr{signif(cor.test(d$x,d$y)$p.value,2)}$}. 

\item The regression line have an intercept of about \Sexpr{signif(coef(model)[1],2)}  and a slope of about \Sexpr{signif(coef(model)[2],2)}.
\end{enumerate}

Ok, for the shake of of accuracy, the exact equation is:  

\[ y = \Sexpr{coef(model)[1]} + \Sexpr{coef(model)[2]} x \]


That plotted in nice LaTeX look like this: 


<<plot,echo=F,fig.cap="The plot.",fig.pos="h", fig.width = 4, fig.height = 4, out.width = "\\linewidth",dev="tikz">>=

plot(d$x, d$y, 
     xlab = "X values", ylab = "Y values", pch = 19, col = "blue")
abline(model, col = "red", lwd = 2,cex=2)
coefficients <- coef(model)
slope <- coefficients[2]
intercept <- coefficients[1]
text(
  x = min(d$x) + 20, 
  y = max(d$y) - 5, 
  labels = paste0("y = ", round(intercept, 3)," + "
                  , round(slope, 3),"x"))
@

\end{document} 


Thanks for this cool solution. But for the moment it is beyond my knowledge of TeX. The compiling in overleaf is not working. I use overleaf. (And I don't of any knwoledge of R. I work with GEOGEBRA with my students. But for the test, I will not use  a computer, so therefore I give the regression line and correlation, so the only thing they have to do is interprete the figures.

(1) Not tested, but in  Overleaf should work just naming the file whathever.Rtex. (2) R is just an advanced calculator, you need only some notions to input and managing data  (vectors, matrices, data frames or lists) an you will realize how easy is make any kind of plots or statistics (3) It is for exams without computers when make the sense present the same problem with different values. Then  a simple  question as "which value is the showed equation is the slope?" cannot be answered  just copying the  answer of the deskmate.

Here's a probably less code intense approach. Unfortunately I can only show you the recipe, as I have next to zero experience with the pgf-functions involved. But I think an other user can fill the coding gaps more easily.
Here's the recipe, using only, what's already available from pgfplots, using symbols known from robust technology development:
(P.S.: You can skip the L-calculation and get R2 from b, r and St alone by simple replacements.)

Code for this image:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

 \section{What's available from pgfplots}
 
 Via \emph{pgfplotstableregressiona} and \emph{-b} from \emph{pgfplots} you have already calculated:
 
 \begin{eqnarray}
     b &=& \frac{\sum(x_i-x_m)(y_i-y_m)}{\sum(x_i-x_m)^2} = \frac{L}{r}\\    
     y_m &=& a + b \times x_m
 \end{eqnarray}  
 
 Via key \emph{variance=\{$<column\ name>$\}} you can calculate both
 
  \begin{eqnarray}
        r &=&  \sum(x_i-x_m)^2\\
        S_t &=&\sum(y_i-y_m)^2
  \end{eqnarray} 
 
 \section{Where you need to go}
   \begin{eqnarray}
        R^2 &=& \frac{(\sum(x_i-x_m)(y_i-y_m))^2}{(\sum(x_i-x_m)^2)(\sum(y_i-y_m)^2)}\\
         &=& \frac{L^2}{r \times S_t}
  \end{eqnarray} 
 
 \section{How to go there}
 
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Calculate&from/via in pgfplots\\
    \midrule
    $b$             & pgfplotstableregressionb\\
    $r = Var(x)$    & variance\\
    $S_t = Var(y)$  & variance\\
    \midrule
    $L = b \times r$& (math)\\
    \midrule
    $R^2 = \frac{L^2}{r \times S_t}$& (math)\\
    \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 
\end{document}

P.S.2: Though the recipe remains valid, the term variance is used in a misleading way in the pgfmanual. It does not calculate for a data column, but assumes to be just some data given with each point ...

